# Photo in shipping method

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods

I have a Magento module that implements some forms of sending, and these send forms come from an API, I wanted to be able to put a photo next to the checkbox of each method. as in the example image. I did not want to tamper with the internal structure of Magento, since this is a custom module and the client will install it alone.
[image]

Each red square would be a photo. Sorry for any translation error. thanks to who to help me.

*Magento 1.9*